# Need sudo to run erlang escript, even though the file has execute permissions

Tags: shell, unix, erlang

I'm trying to create a file called `factorial` that can run from the command line using escript in erlang. I'm actually copying the exact file from the [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html).

My problem is that even though I did `chmod u+x factorial` (and later `chmod a+x factorial`) I am unable to simply do `./factorial 5`. I checked using `ls -l` that my file has the correct permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 josh  staff     402 Jul 24 18:43 factorial
```

I am only able to run the file successfully if I do `sudo ./factorial 5`, which is a pain because my password is long and I don't want to have to use sudo every time.

The error I get when I don't use sudo is the following:

```
josh@MacBook-Pro test % ./factorial 5
2020-07-24 19:02:53.247288 
    args: []
    format: "Error when reading /Users/josh/.erlang.cookie: eacces"
    label: {error_logger,error_msg}
2020-07-24 19:02:53.247466 supervisor_report   #{label=>{supervisor,start_error},report=>[{supervisor,{local,net_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{"Error when reading /Users/josh/.erlang.cookie: eacces",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,286}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,140}]},{gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,374}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,342}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{id,auth},{mfargs,{auth,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,2000},{child_type,worker}]}]}
2020-07-24 19:02:53.247492 crash_report        #{label=>{proc_lib,crash},report=>[[{initial_call,{auth,init,['Argument__1']}},{pid,<0.59.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{error,"Error when reading /Users/josh/.erlang.cookie: eacces",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,286}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,140}]},{gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,374}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,342}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}},{ancestors,[net_sup,kernel_sup,<0.47.0>]},{message_queue_len,0},{messages,[]},{links,[<0.57.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,987},{stack_size,27},{reductions,894}],[]]}
2020-07-24 19:02:53.247955 supervisor_report   #{label=>{supervisor,start_error},report=>[{supervisor,{local,kernel_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{"Error when reading /Users/josh/.erlang.cookie: eacces",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,286}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,140}]},{gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,374}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,342}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}}}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{id,net_sup},{mfargs,{erl_distribution,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,infinity},{child_type,supervisor}]}]}
2020-07-24 19:02:53.249031 crash_report        #{label=>{proc_lib,crash},report=>[[{initial_call,{application_master,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2','Argument__3','Argument__4']}},{pid,<0.46.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{"Error when reading /Users/josh/.erlang.cookie: eacces",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,286}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,140}]},{gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,374}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,342}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}},[{application_master,init,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,138}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}},{ancestors,[<0.45.0>]},{message_queue_len,1},{messages,[{'EXIT',<0.47.0>,normal}]},{links,[<0.45.0>,<0.44.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,987},{stack_size,27},{reductions,184}],[]]}
2020-07-24 19:02:53.249780 std_info            #{label=>{application_controller,exit},report=>[{application,kernel},{exited,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{"Error when reading /Users/josh/.erlang.cookie: eacces",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,286}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,140}]},{gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,374}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,342}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}},{type,permanent}]}
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{\"Error when reading /Users/josh/.erlang.cookie: eacces\",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,\"auth.erl\"},{line,286}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,\"auth.erl\"},{line,140}]},{gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,374}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,342}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,\"proc_lib.erl\"},{line,249}]}]}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{"Error when reading /Users/josh/.erla

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
```

At first I thought the issue might be permissions for the `/Users/josh/.erlang.cookie` file, but changing permissions for that brings up an error because apparently only the owner can have read permissions for that file.

So, what do I need to do so that I can run the file with `./factorial 5` and not have to use `sudo ./factorial 5`?

Comment: Try deleting `.erlang.cookie` and then executing the script `sudo rm /Users/josh/.erlang.cookie` and then `./factorial 5`.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  or [unix.se], but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `/Users/josh/.erlang.cookie` is owned by root instead of your own user. You can just delete it (it will be recreated automatically), or change the owner with:

```
sudo chown josh /Users/josh/.erlang.cookie
```